# How to render component's child instead of entire component

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-portal

I have the `react-bnb-gallery` package with single default exported component named `ReactBnbGallery`. It shows the gallery through the portal and  works well but my goal is to get that gallery inline in html and nested in components tree.

Currently what I have:

```
<SomeWrapperComponent>
  <ReactBnbGallery />     // contains not accessible <Gallery/> 
<SomeWrapperComponent />
```

and I want this:

```
<SomeWrapperComponent>
  <Gallery/> 
<SomeWrapperComponent />
```

In this way I want to omit the portal and have the gallery right inside my layout. 
Any suggestions???

I thought about some HOC over the `<ReactBnbGallery>`
or maybe Portals have some api or another switcher to simply turning off

Thanx in advance !

Comment: Hi @andrdrx, I'm working on that. When the new changes are ready, the <Gallery /> component could be rendered directly, without the <ReactBnbGallery /> wrapper. I suggest you to open this question as an issue in the gallery repository at https://github.com/peterpalau/react-bnb-gallery/issues.

Answer (score 0):

The `Gallery` component is now accessible outside the portal.

This is now possible using the following code:

```
import { Gallery } from 'react-bnb-gallery';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Gallery photos={[...]} />
);
```

If you want to use also the main `ReactBnbGallery` component, the new way is doing the following:

```
import { ReactBnbGallery } from 'react-bnb-gallery';

const MyComponent = () => (
  { /* ReactBnbGallery wraps the Gallery component */ }
  <ReactBnbGallery photos={[...]} />
);
```

The updates have been published in [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bnb-gallery) with the new version [1.1.7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bnb-gallery/v/1.1.7).